# SQL join child with multiple key value pairs

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query for MySQL that selects all parents where there are child records for every condition. My schema is more complicated than this but this is the idea.

For example:

## parent_table:

---

*id, ....*

## child_table

---

*parent_id, id, key, value*

So,

```sql
SELECT pt.id FROM parent_table pt
JOIN child_table ct ON pt.id = ct.parent_id
WHERE **AllOfTheseExist** (ct.key = "keyName1" AND ct.value = "value1")
                  AND (ct.key = "keyName2" AND ct.value = "value2")
```

If I 'or' them together it works great but I need it to be exclusive, not inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is ct.key cannot equal both keyname1 and keyname2 in the same row.  You either need to check the child table multiple times or use conditional aggregation.  Here's one option using `exists`:

```
SELECT id 
FROM parent_table pt
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM child_table ct
   WHERE pt.id = ct.parent_id
      AND ct.key = 'keyName1' 
      AND ct.value = 'value1') AND EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM child_table ct
   WHERE pt.id = ct.parent_id
       ct.key = 'keyName2' AND 
       ct.value = 'value2')
```

Or you could use conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from parent_table pt 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from child_table ct 
    where pt.id = ct.parent_id
    group by ct.parent_id
    having sum(case when ct.key = 'keyname1' and ct.value = 'value1' 
               then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and 
          sum(case when ct.key = 'keyname2' and ct.value = 'value2' 
               then 1 else 0 end) > 0 )
```

---

Maybe one other option using `distinct` with multiple `joins`:

```
select distinct pt.id
from parent_table pt
   join child_table ct1 on pt.id = ct1.parent_id and 
                           ct1.key = 'keyname1' and  
                           ct1.value = 'value1' 
   join child_table ct2 on pt.id = ct2.parent_id and 
                           ct2.key = 'keyname1' and  
                           ct2.value = 'value1'
```

Comment: The third option worked like a champ. My schema is quit a bit more complicated so I don't think the first two options are viable.

Comment: @Gremash -- Glad it worked, I figured I could list a couple different options! `Exists` may be faster in some circumstances, but the `join` option is definitely cleaner.